# Display list of posts with x tag within a page?

Tags: pages, tags

What codex/query would I use to call a list of pages with a specific tag from within another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabbly the easest way to do it is use: [Kalin's Post List](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kalins-post-list/screenshots/)

> Creates a shortcode or PHP snippet for inserting dynamic, highly customizable lists of posts or pages such as related posts or table of contents into your post content or theme.

so you can either use a shortcode or edit your theme file.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, will check out the plugin